# What does Twitter API listed_count indicate?

Tags: twitter

Quick question, I am having an issue finding information about this label...

what does the API user_listed_count indicate?

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation, the number of public lists that this user is a member of. [full documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/data-dictionary/overview/user-object)

```
"listed_count": 9274
```